# Making laravel eloquent relation of parent model with child model, by putting a condition on parent to get child data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to make a relationship from parent model to child model and want to put a condition on parent to get data. Like if the "vanity" column from parent is equal to "INV" then get the data of the child by maching the transid of both. vanity is a column in AT.

```
class AT extends Model
{
    public function relate_voucher_to_invoice()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class, 'transid', 'transid')
            ->where('vanity', '=', 'INV');
    }
}
```

I tried to get the data of invoice using the relation if vanity of the AT table is equal to INV. But got a problem that vanity is not a column of Invoice table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the join method within the relationship definition to apply the condition involving the vanity column.

```
class AT extends Model
{
    public function relate_voucher_to_invoice()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class, 'transid', 'transid')
            ->join('ats', 'invoices.transid', '=', 'ats.transid')
            ->where('ats.vanity', '=', 'INV');
    }
}
```